# How can Paypal redirect to my website?

Tags: php, paypal

I create a function for admin of my website send money back to users using Paypal. I created a button with Paypal. My problem is: when Admin login Paypal with business account then he send money to personal account, Paypal do not redirect to my website.

Here is my code

```
<form target="myWindowPayment" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payPalForm">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $idProject ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="charly@zondertag.net">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base_url() ?>crowdpp/backingProject/3">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel" value="<?php echo base_url() ?>crowdpp/backingProject/3">
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" id="item_name" value="Pledging for <?php echo $result->title ?> project" size="45">
<input name="amount" type="hidden" id="amount" value="<?php echo $pledgeAmount ?>" size="45">
</form>
```

Comment: Try login to your sandbox account and the go to Profile --> My selling Tools--> Website Payment Preferences . There should be an option "Auto Return" , Turn it on and provide the return url there . Save the settings and try to process the payment once again .

Answer (score 0):

In payment integration,we get two results.

```
    1.successful payment
    2.unsuccessful payment
```

put success page name in return url if successful payment.put failure page name in cancelurl if unsuccessful payment.example.

```
$setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails->ReturnURL = "http://localhost:8080/success.php";
$setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails->CancelURL = "http://localhost:8080/cancel.php";
```

Comment: You can see my code. Please help me with my code. I think something working with <input type="hidden" name="business" value="charly@zondertag.net">, but I don't know how to fix because account receiver is personal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo urlencode(base_url().'crowdpp/backingProject/3'); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo urlencode(base_url().'crowdpp/backingProject/3'); ?>">
```